# installing R shiny in Rstudio getting error

Tags: r, installation

[image]

I want to install r shiny in r studio. However there was error in the installing process. I screenshot the error message. Could someone help to resolve the error?

Comment: Did you change your default lib path by any chance? It seems a bit odd R is not trying to install the packages into a personal directory. What version if Windows is this? Did you install R yourself? Possibly with a different user account? Maybe [check permissions](https://protechguides.com/how-to-check-folder-permissions-on-windows/) on the library directory in the error message. And check that with [your current user name](https://www.windows-commandline.com/current-logged-in-user-name-command/)

Comment: https://community.rstudio.com/t/error-after-r-update-lib-c-program-files-r-r-3-5-0-library-is-not-writable/7947 https://community.rstudio.com/t/package-installation-error-library-is-not-writable/19173/3

Comment: You don't have write access to where packages are installed.

Comment: Yes, when I run by administrator it worked. Thanks Axeman!